# epipolar lines not parallel for rectified images

Tags: stereo-3d, fundamental-matrix

I calculated the fundamental matrix of stereo view, I rectified both images using that fundamental matrix
now the epipolar lines should be parallel to the x-axis
 to prove this, I calculate again the fundamental matrix for the rectified images to check if it gives
 F=[i]x the antisymmetric matrix representing the cross product with i

you can clearly see in the image that the marked points have the same y (height) however the epipolar lines arent' parallel:

[image: you can clearly see in the image that the marked points have the same y (height) however the epipolar lines arent' parallel.]

F that I found is:

```
   F=[[ 1.89693346e-06 -1.75374506e-04 -2.16090418e-02]
     [ 1.99776626e-04 -1.71071653e-05 -1.89981986e-01]
     [ 2.16519377e-02  1.89151983e-01  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Can you draw the same thing without the 3-d effect, so that the image plane is in the screen plane?

Comment: Alex Kreimer, this is not a 3d effect , this is the effect of rectification, where many image points are out of range

Comment: Not sure what you mean. 
 Anyway, maybe you can plot the rectified pair like this: http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~yuhuang/rectify/rectif_4_5_bd.JPG

Comment: yess this is where I want to get to, I want to get a parallel epipolars, regardless how rectified images are plotted
I used the open cv cv2.findFundamentalMat to calculate F but somehow I am not getting the right one F should be = [i]x but unfortuantly I am getting other values

Comment: It may be that your epipolar lines are already ok and what you see as 'non-parallel' is because of the way the images are drawn.  Don't forget that (even the 'parallel') epipolar lines meet at the epipole :)

Comment: if this would be the case shouldn't F be =[0 0 0;0 0 -1;0 1 0]

Comment: Yes, it should (maybe up to scale).  You want to post your code?